# what are the openemr metrics to analyse the clinical data

Tags: c#, google-analytics, content-management-system

Currently am working on Open Electronic Medical Records(Open E M R) Portal analysis,I need some metrics which are related to clinical data(patient,doctors etc),So what metrics should i consider to make some application level analysis,
Can you people suggest me some healthcare related metrics to analyse the clinical data as well as application and i have gone through many healthcare related articles but i didn't find of them.Can you guys please help in choosing the correct metrics related to Open Electronic Medical Records(Open E M R) clinical data.